# What is an untrusted assembly in the context of unsafe code in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I'm struggling to understand one of the limitations of unsafe code in C#. Quoting from the Microsoft reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx):

> In the common language runtime (CLR), unsafe code is referred to as unverifiable code. Unsafe code in C# is not necessarily dangerous; it is just code whose safety cannot be verified by the CLR. The CLR will therefore only execute unsafe code if it is in a fully trusted assembly

What is a fully trusted assembly? What causes an assembly to not be fully trusted? Will using a library that uses unsafe code limit how my own code can be deployed/run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This refers to a [deprecated feature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd233103) called Partial Trust.

Partial Trust was never very robust, and is no longer supported or recommended.

As of .Net 4, all code runs with full trust, unless a custom CLR host configures the CLR differently.